# What happens on heating an ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, esters, elimination

While solving a few questions a came across a problem which asked me what would happen when sec-butyl ethanoate was heated.

I had never read about this reaction before and took to researching through a few of my textbooks, but could not find an explanation as to what would happen.

I also thought along the lines free radical formations and tried to make an attempt.

However according to the answer the reaction was a syn elimination and it would give a Hoffmann product. But I couldn't get any more information out of it.

But now I was stumped. So please help me out of you know anything about this.

[image: compound]

Edit:

After googling for sometime I came across a paper which said that this particular compound would decompose to give cis butene.

However I could not understand the reason for this. Here is where I saw it:
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/i360047a014

Comment: Depending upon the zeolite employed with sec-butyl acetate in your link, the cis/trans ratio varied between less and greater than one. cis-Butene is not the exclusive butene formed.

Comment: @user55119 Okay! Noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of a Thermal *syn* elimination. The Wikipedia article is a good place to start: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ei_mechanism)

[image]

image from [here](https://edubuzznotes.com/pyrolytic-syn-or-thermal-elimination-regioselectivity-of-e1-e2-reaction-organic-chemistry/)

From ref 2

> Unsymmetrical Acetate and xanthate esters yield a mixture of all the possible alkenes, but there is usually a predominance of the more highly substituted alkene.